# Wanted: Family of 6

Tags: riddle

After many years, authorities are still looking for a family of 6, five of whom are suspected of many multiple-country border crossings with no passports or proper identification. Although no known damage has been done, the homeland security divisions of many countries are irate, and continue "to spend much time and money until these 6 are found and punished."

A recent tip led investigators to believe that 5 of the 6 are still actively on the run, and that these 5 meet with the 6th member (believed to be the leader) at the same time each day, presumably to plan future evasion tactics. However, no sightings of any of the 6 have been documented, leaving authorities puzzled.

On multiple occasions, top intelligence in many different countries led several police forces to some of the family members' projected locations, but each time officers have reported an eerie feeling of 1 or more members of the family being extremely close to them, yet none were seen.

**The official, but limited, suspect information:**

> 1. Priscilla, mother and leader, at least 8 counts of trespassing, claims her children are not doing any harm, and that she has trained them on the straight and narrow path their whole lives
> 2. Ed, tallest sibling, 13 counts of trespassing, the most famous of the 5 siblings worldwide
> 3. Caitlin, 17 counts of trespassing
> 4. Cadence, twin sister of Caitlin, at least 12 counts of trespassing
> 5. Arnold, 8 counts of trespassing
> 6. Anthony, twin brother of Arnold, multiple counts of aiding and abetting

**Who are these six?**

Comment: Who are they? Of course they are Priscilla, Ed, Caitlin, Cadence, Arnold and Anthony!

Comment: Are the names important, or just for flavor?

Comment: Why am I thinking of constellations?

Comment: @EngineerToast Maybe the twin brothers made you subconsciously think of Gemini?

Comment: Wow, brilliant riddle!

Comment: I am thinking of some kind of trail, but I am not sure

Comment: @RootVegetable Sorry, I missed your comment from earlier. Yes, the names are kind of hints, in a way.

Comment: Should throw in Andrew, the ex-husband who never sees Priscilla but still visits the kids. He's only got 2 cases of trespassing.

Comment: Or maybe he'd be the current husband, because they're always touching.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

They are:

> Various lines on the earth and the number of countries each passes through.

Priscilla, mother and leader, at least 8 counts of trespassing, claims her children are not doing any harm, and that she has trained them on the straight and narrow path their whole lives

> **Prime Meridian**: UK, France, Spain, Algeria, Mali, Burkina Faso, Togo and Ghana

Ed, tallest sibling, 13 counts of trespassing, the most famous of the 5 worldwide

> **Equator**:  Ecuador, Colombia, Brazil, Sao Tome & Principe, Gabon, Republic of the Congo, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Uganda, Kenya, Somalia, Maldives, Indonesia and Kiribati

Caitlin, 17 counts of trespassing

> **Tropic of Cancer**: Bahamas, Mexico, Mauritania, Mali, Western Sahara, Algeria, Niger, Libya, Egypt, Saudi Arabia, India, China, United Arab Emirates, Oman, Bangladesh, Burma and Taiwan

Cadence, twin sister of Caitlin, at least 12 counts of trespassing

> **Tropic of Capricorn**: Brazil, Paraguay, Argentina, Chile, South Africa, Botswana, Namibia, Australia, Madagascar, Mozambique, France (French Polynesia + New Caledonia), Tonga, Fiji, New Zealand (Cook Islands)

Arnold, 8 counts of trespassing

> **Arctic Circle**:  Norway, Sweden, Finland, Russia, United States (Alaska), Canada, Denmark (Greenland), and Iceland

Anthony, twin brother of Arnold, multiple counts of aiding and abetting

> **Antarctic Circle**: No countries

Bonus clues:

> All the lines are "straight and narrow".  The Equator is the longest of the 5 siblings, hence the "tallest".  The two tropics and the two circles are "twins" of each other as they are matched pairs in the north and south.

Comment: Damn, this is good! Brilliant answer. I was trying to match them to the James Bond actors (Sean Connery = Ed, Pierce Brosnan = Priscilla, etc.), but you're obviously right :-P

Comment: @randal'thor Initially I thought they were time zones (Pacific, Eastern, Central, etc).  But that didn't fit.  I also considered rivers, mountain ranges, continents, and oceans before I thought of Equator being E.

Comment: You made a mistake with the Priscilla spoiler. Burkina Faso is one country, not 2.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Thanks, I will correct it.

Comment: Why five of six is on the run? I'd say it's the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

What if they are...

> Ghosts?

It's kind of a silly answer, but

> They've reportedly been seen worldwide, yet have never been spotted in person, nor have they been reported boarding any sort of aircraft or boat.

In addition,

> Police forces have not seen a single one of them, yet felt an eerie feeling as if at least one of them was near.

This can be backed up with real life evidence:

> Throughout the countless reports of "haunted" structures and such, a lot of people exploring said places often experience a feeling of being watched, even if no one else is there.

Comment: I think the numbers in the OP are somehow important