# A family of movie lovers

Tags: riddle, pattern, movies

In this family, each member has their favorite movies:

**Daniel**: Interstellar, Top Gun, True Grit
**Deanna**: The Fast and the Furious, Life of Pi, The Wizard of Oz
**Louise**: Babe, Excalibur, Legion
**Michelle**: The Grey, How to Train Your Dragon, The Parent Trap
**Neal**: Cast Away, Gulliver's Travels, Romeo Must Die
**Piper**: Flashdance, Madagascar, The Princess Bride
**Taylor**: Cars, Goodfellas, Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl
**Wayne**: Dances with Wolves, Harry Potter and the Sorceror's Stone,  Midnight in Paris

Who are these people and why do they like these movies?

Hint:

> The 24 movies are liked for the following reasons:
>
>  * Types of characters (not always the main characters) (17)
>  * The main character (2)
>  * The actor/actress playing the main character (2)
>  * Things in the movie (2)
>  * The movie title (1)

Comment: Technically the 2012 film [Life of Pi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi_(film)) does not have a leading 'The'. Does this affect the puzzle?

Comment: @stiv Fixed.  It doesn't affect the puzzle.

Comment: ate you sure about riddle instead of pattern? if so, is the word tag applicable?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I based the tags on [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/wanted-family-of-6/14763#14763) which had only a riddle tag, but pattern does seem to fit better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that each person represents a

> City in the US with the same first **two** letters

And the movies involve

> Characters whose names derive from sports teams from that city

**Daniel:** Interstellar, Top Gun, True Grit

> **Dallas:** Stars, Mavericks, Cowboys

**Deanna:** The Fast and the Furious, Life of Pi, The Wizard of Oz

> **Detroit:** Pistons, Tigers, Lions

**Louise:** Babe, Excalibur, Legion

> **Los Angeles:** Rams, Kings, Angels

**Michelle:** The Grey, How to Train Your Dragon, The Parent Trap

> **Minnesota:** Timberwolves, Vikings, Twins

**Neal:** Cast Away, Gulliver's Travels, Romeo Must Die

> **New York:** Islanders, Giants, Jets (Jet Li is the actor)

**Piper:** Flashdance, Madagascar, The Princess Bride

> **Pittsburgh:** Steelers, Penguins, Pirates (thanks kayzeroshort and OP, although I still like *Vengeance* for this one)

**Taylor:** Cars, Goodfellas, Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl

> **Tampa:** Lightning (Lightning McCloud is a character in Cars), Rays (thanks kayzeroshort), Buccaneers

**Wayne:** Dances with Wolves, Harry Potter and the Sorceror's Stone, Midnight in Paris

> **Washington:** Redskins (Native Americans), Wizards, Capitals (Paris is the capital of France)

Comment: Nice work! I'm thinking these are the intended answers: rot13(Cvengrf sbe Cevaprff Oevqr; Enlf sbe Tbbqsryynf (Enl Yvbggn)),; though your answers also work :)

Comment: Kayzeroshort is right about those two.  Think rot13(Qernq Cvengr Eboregf) for The Princess Bride.  The others are all correct.  BTW, the names have the first *two* letters in common!  Oh and I just had a thought that I should have put Hellboy as the movie instead of Dances with Wolves.  Too bad I didn't think of it.